# Can a father ever be the Kohen at his sons Pidyon Haben?

Tags: kohen-priest, pidyon-haben

I'm looking for a scenario where a father can potentially be the Kohen for his own son's Pidyon Haben.

Normally, this would be impossible, because a Kohen is *pattur* from Pidyon Haben. Is there any scenario where this would be possible?

Comment: Maybe if the mom is a gentile who converts while pregnant?

Comment: In that case would he be the father (halachically) after the conversion? And if yes, would the son be a kohen?

Comment: No, but you have to give up on something if you want answers here. The answer below gives up on a pidyon ceremony, and hence any semblance of the regular mitzva. This gives up on halakhic relationship. No one knows why you want this info so who can tell which is more useful.

Answer (score 3):

If the son is a *challal*. If a Kohen fathers a *challal*, the son is not a Kohen and therefore needs to be redeemed. However, there is no 'ceremony', because the father is זוכה בפדיונו automatically. So he is the Kohen, but there is no actual Pidyon. (See Bechoros 47b)

Comment: I thought someone who has a parent who is a Kohen or Levi is exempt. If someone's mother (bas Kohen) exempts them, why not a father?

Comment: @Robev - See Rema 305 about Ben Challal